# Is there a way to check for double whitespaces in an XML, if these double whitespaces are only visible in text-view (e.g. in the browser)?

Tags: xml, whitespace

The problem at hand is, that in the course of some XML transformations the auto-formatting wrongly inserted whitespaces. I cannot automatically remove them, because the encoding scheme for the data is too complex (lots of nested elements).
What I would like to do is to interpret the XML as String (e.g. Browser View) and remove every first whitespace in case of a double whitespace. Is that even possible?

To give a simple example:

```
Ihrem Rechtsanwalt Herrn Dr. <rs ref="#2345" type="person"> Oskar Samek </rs> erliegende Korrespondenz
```

Whitespaces were inserted within the "rs" tag, so now a double whitespace appears when opened in a browser for example.
In text-view, it looks like this:
Ihrem Rechtsanwalt Herrn Dr.__Oskar Samek__erliegende Korrespondenz

I absolutely need to remove the double whitespace AT LEAST in the text-view, optimally even in the XML itself. It that possible?

If needed I will provide more info.

Comment: Why don't you just apply `normalize-space()`on the `<rs...>` element like this: `normalize-space(rs)`? In this example this would solve your problem. And, following on, you could apply this transformation on _all_ `<rs>` elements in your whole file, if you wanted.

Comment: But does it remove double whitespace that occur due to nested tags as well? 

I would need to apply it to the whole document, I am not sure which tags are affected. I am afraid to delete either not enough or (even worse) too much.

Comment: I do not know anything about your source file. You can either try it out or provide a [mcve] which would increase your chance of getting a perfectly-fitting answer.

Comment: apart from that, there could be cases where the only space between two words comes from within tags, so I am not sure if I can just remove all.
I would need a method to verify if there are actually two whitespaces

edit: okay, give me some time I will try it out and find a better example. thank you